# Xcode : read plist data and display them as text

Tags: xcode, applescript, appdelegate

I totally forgot about Xcode AppleScript Application.

Basically, the application will read value from plist file.

My applescript to read this variable is

```
set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/example.plist"

tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    -- read the plist data
    set theNameFromPlist to value of property list item "theName" of p_list
    set theEmailFromPlist to value of property list item "theEmail" of p_list
    set thecreationDateFromPlist to value of property list item "creationDate" of p_list


end tell
```

now how do I integrate this to Xcode?

Should I go on AppDelegate.applescript and add wherever after "applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)"  this script ?

```
followed by  property NametextField : theNameFromPlist
```

I'm probably totally wrong here, just can't think.
PS swift will do it if any easier

Comment: In Xcode forget `System Events` and use the native Cocoa classes in AppleScriptObjC.

Answer (score 1):

Like vadian said in the comments, In Xcode, System Events won't run properly so you can just use the native Cocoa classes but I prefer to
use "do shell script" applescript/asobjc command and run the "defaults" command so here is a way to do that when the application will finish launching:

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    set plistFile to "~/Desktop/example.plist"
    set theNameFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " theName"
    set theEmailFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " theEmail"
    set theCreationDateFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " creationDate"
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

And if you are trying to display the name in a TextField on a Window
in the Interface Builder you can just add Modify the code to this:

```
property nameTextField : missing value

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    set plistFile to "~/Desktop/example.plist"
    set theNameFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " theName"
    set theEmailFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " theEmail"
    set theCreationDateFromPlist to do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " creationDate"
    tell nameTextField to setStringValue_(theNameFromPlist)
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

(make sure to connect the property nameTextField to a TextField in the Interface Builder)

hope this Helped!! :D

Comment: That's look great, I will give it a try when I can, many thanks

Comment: BTW, For more complicated directories with \ slashes e.g.. /Applications/My\ Awesome\ App.app/ then I recommend modifing the code little e.g. do shell script "defaults read " & plistFile & " theName", use: do shell script "defaults read \"" & plistFile & "\" theName" (I did not add the \" before because when using ~/ in "\, It does not work properly but glad i could help)

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning Cocoa classes I actually meant this

```
set plistFile to POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "example.plist"
set thePlist to (current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFile) as record
set theNameFromPlist to thePlist's theName
set theEmailFromPlist to thePlist's theEmail
```

To add new key value pairs and write the plist back to disk add

```
set thePlist to thePlist & {stringKey:"Foo", booleanKey:false}
set cocoaDictionary to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:thePlist
cocoaDictionary's writeToFile:plistFile atomically:true
```

Comment: This is very useful! How would I go about writing to (i.e. modifying) an item in the plist? The above commands all seem to be for reading only. I have a string and a boolean what I would like to write to the file. Could you perhaps add that part where data gets saved back into the plist? That would help me out a lot.

Comment: I am confused because I am looking to take the value of a text field and the state of a checkbox and update them in the plist. Initially, I use your top code to read data from the plist and set the text/state of the components. Now, I have added a save button to write the data back without replacing the entire file (just updating the value). Something along the lines of: `set thePlist's savedText to guiTextbox's stringValue()`. Is there an easy way to update the single value with something simple as that?

Comment: Of course you can do that but since you are dealing with AppleScript text at the moment you have to coerce the type `set thePlist's savedText to guiTextbox's stringValue() as text`. Then write the dictionary back (last two lines of the second snippet)